# what's the GUI framework visual studio is using by default?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

as far as i know, visual studio is a GUI code generator among other things, you drag a button and put it on the window, a code is written for you behind the scene.

my Question is:

what's the GUI framework Visual studio is using by default???
i know it integrates with some GUI toolkits as Fox, GTK and QT .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Visual Studio doesn't integrate with other GUI toolkits; the toolkits may integrate with VS. For instance, Qt provides integration with Visual Studio, so you can develop Qt apps from within the VS IDE.

Visual Studio itself supports development for several frameworks:

1. Raw Win32 (OK, not really a framework, but I thought I'd mention it for completeness; and there is a dialog editor)
2. MFC for C++ (crude support for GUI design)
3. WTL for C++ (no support for GUI design, AFAIK; it's all code)
4. Windows Forms for .Net
5. WPF for .Net

I don't know that it makes sense to speak of a default framework. Windows Forms is, I think, the most commonly used today, with WPF rising in popularity (or maybe I'm out of date).

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010, itself, uses [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) for it's user interface.  It can be used to create applications using any GUI framework, however, and comes with template projects for WPF, Windows Forms, and MFC (C++) for GUIs.